# キーボードから入力した値をファイルに保存する。十文字を超える場合や入力値がない場合はファイルを閉じる。

Tags: java

キーボートから入力してファイルに保管するのはできたのですが、十文字以上、入力がない場合に条件がうまく処理できません。以下作成したプログラム。
どのような内容を追加したうまく動くでしょうか。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main4 {

    public static void main4(String[] args)  throws IOException{

        System.out.println("キーボードから10文字以内で入力してください");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String str = null;
        try {
            str = br.readLine();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/java.txt");{

        byte sbyte[] = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        fos.write(sbyte);

            //ファイルに書き込む
            fos.flush();

            //ファイルをクローズする
            fos.close();

        System.out.println("入力された文字は「" + str + "」です");

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String#length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length())の戻り値を文字列の長さとみなしてよいかと思います。

今回、ユーザが入力した文字列は変数 `str` に入っているので、 `str.length()` の戻り値を見て条件分岐することになります。

```java
// 入力した文字列の長さ
int length = str.length();

if (0 < length && length <= 10) {
    // 0文字より多く10文字以下の場合

    // 既に実装している「キーボードから入力した値をファイルに保存する」処理

} else {
    // 十文字を超えるか入力値がない場合

    //ファイルをクローズする
    fos.close();

    System.out.println("十文字を超えるか入力値がない場合");
}
```